# Kotlin - make sure a collection operation finishes before starting the next one

Tags: kotlin, collections, sequence

If write the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    letters.map { print(it); it }.forEach { print(it) }
}
```

I get this output: `abcdabcd`

However if I change it to be a sequence instead:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val letters = listOf("a", "b", "c", "d")
    letters.asSequence().map { print(it); it }.forEach { print(it) }
}
```

I get the following: `aabbccdd`

It seems that Kotlin's sequences do not guarantee that a "group operation" (e.g. `map` or `forEach`) will finish before the other starts but that when we apply these operations to collections there's the guarantee that the operations will be done one at the time.

How can we guarantee that a "group operation" such as `map` or `forEach` will be applied to all the elements in a collection or a sequence before starting to execute the next chained "group operation"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can we guarantee that a "group operation" such as map or forEach will be applied to all the elements in a collection or a sequence before starting to execute the next chained "group operation"?

The behavior depends on whether the input is a `Collection` or a `Sequence`.

- Collections will apply a single operation in the chain to every element in the collection before then applying the next operation in the chain. This is why you see `"abcd"` once and then `"abcd"` again.
- Sequences will apply every operation in the chain to each element in the sequence before then applying all operations to the next element in the sequence. This is why you see `"aa"`, then `"bb"`, etc.

The main thing to understand is that Kotlin sequences are *lazy*. Whenever you transform a `Sequence` (e.g. through `map` or other function), that transformation is *also* applied lazily. It is only when you actually evaluate an element in the sequence (in your case, this is done by `forEach`) that the transformations are applied.

If you need `Collection` behavior from a `Sequence`, you have to first transform the sequence to a collection. You can call `sequence.toList()` or otherwise transform it, but there's no way to get "eager" behavior from a `Sequence` out of the box.

---

Let's walk through the two different scenarios.

#### When `letters` is a `List<String>`

Lists are not lazy. In order to `map` one `List` to another, we must walk through the entire input list, transform each element, and build the output list. With that in mind...

The first operation, `map { print(it); it }`, reads each value from the input, prints it, and creates a new list. It returns a list holding `"a", "b", "c", "d"` and the program has printed `"abcd"`.

The second operation, `forEach { print(it) }`, iterates over the list and prints each element. When this operation is complete, the program has printed `"abcd"` again, for a total output of `"abcdabcd"`.

#### When `letters` is a `Sequence<String>`

Sequences are lazy. In order to `map` one `Sequence` to another, the program retains the transformation method and waits until *someone else* actually needs a value before performing the transformation. So...

The first operation creates a new `TransformingSequence` that holds both the original sequence and the `print(it); return it` transformer. It returns this new sequence and the program has not yet printed anything.

The second operation is "terminal" (i.e. it actually evaluates each element in the sequence). It iterates over the sequence and prints each element. But remember: the sequence we're iterating over is a `TransformingSequence` that itself prints each element! So the first `print` action in the `forEach` call prints `"aa"`, the second prints `"bb"`, and so on, for a total output of `"aabbccdd"`.